# Spring: Eclipse stopped recognize java class but everything works

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Eclipse suddenly stopped recognize file as java class. I'm little confused because everything works, but this one class isn't highlighted as java syntax. Instead, beside class name editor shows strange icon: file with purple curly braces. Does anyone know what that mean and how to fix it?

Comment: Please show a screenshot about what you talk. What happen if you right-click the file and choose _Open With > Java Editor_?

Comment: I solved it. Somehow this class switched to open with Generic Text Editor. Thank you for your help!